# HTTP Error Code 406

Tags: rest, http

I understand that correct use of HTTP Status codes is a good indicator of correct RESTful implementation of a service.  I'm not sure what code to return when the following resource is called with an invalid token to confirm creation of a new user account:

/user/confirmation POST {param is confirmation token}

By best guess is 406 Not Acceptable?  But maybe it's a 200 because there is no error as such in which case the response much include information to indicate a failed confirmation?

Comment: I would put 400. 406 relates to Accept in the header (like, application/json etc) which is different from your example. And 200 "swallows" client error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both [`406`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) and [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) are **unsuitable** for this situation:

- [`406`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6) is meant for content negotiation, when the server cannot send a representation of a particular resource with the media type indicated in the [`Accept`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) header of the request.
- [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) must be used when the operation has succeeded, what's not the case.

You could probably go for the generic [`400`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) to express a bad request or go for [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) to indicate that the request is forbidden.

---

Sending the right status code is as important as proving a payload that describes the problem and helps your client to determine the cause of the error.

For reporting problems in your HTTP API, I advise you to have a look at the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807): it defines simple JSON and XML document formats to inform the client about a problem in a HTTP API and also defines the `application/problem+json` and `application/problem+xml` media types.

---

Michael Kropat put together a [pretty useful set of diagrams](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) to determine the most suitable status code for each situation. See the following diagram for `4xx` status codes:

[image: Picking the right 4xx status code]